# Athena Iceberg Slow On Empty Table

Tags: amazon-athena, apache-iceberg

I am looking at the new Iceberg Tables for AWS Athena. I'm hoping to move my data lake over to Iceberg so that I can significantly reduce the complexity of table partition management and hopefully get some better performance. I created a test iceberge table with two fields: `event_date` and `log`.

```
CREATE TABLE ACME.iceberg_test (
    event_date timestamp, 
    log string
)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
    hour(event_date)
)
LOCATION
    's3://ACME/iceberg_test'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'table_type'='ICEBERG',
    'compaction_bin_pack_target_file_size_bytes'='536870912'
);
```

This creates a new S3 prefix in *ACME* with metadata etc. I query this new empty table an it takes 14s to produce 0 results.

I load it with 20 sample rows:

```
INSERT INTO iceberg_test
VALUES
(timestamp '2021-12-20 01:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 02:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 03:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 04:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 05:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 06:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 07:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 08:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 09:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 10:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 11:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 12:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 13:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 14:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 15:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 16:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 17:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 18:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 19:30:00', 'hello'),
(timestamp '2021-12-20 20:30:00', 'hello');
```

And for good measure run their "OPTIMIZE" command on it which I think only does compaction but thought it might run some partition discovery as well.

```
OPTIMIZE iceberg_test REWRITE DATA
  USING BIN_PACK;
```

But it still takes 14s to return my 20 rows here. It looks like I haven't configured my tables properly and it is not using the partitions efficiently. I even tried adding a partition predicate that is well out of the bounds of the sample data I gave:

```
SELECT * FROM iceberg_test WHERE event_date < timestamp '2021-10-10';
```

Still taking 14s.

I'm not sure what else I'm supposed to do other than register the partitions. Why is my iceberg table not using known partition meta? How can I get Iceberg to do some partition discovery?

Comment: To my surprise it seems like it is normal for this format. Check execution time of queries on this official AWS video. https://youtu.be/u1v666EXCJw Especially query 7.

Comment: I tried this today (May 1, 2020) and it works fine. Insert took a dozen of seconds but select took 3-7 seconds.

Comment: @averbin Still slower than non-iceberg tables. Our definitions of "fine" are not the same.

Comment: Any update on the above? Facing similar issues. I am trying to fire OLAP type queries on a 100 GB dataset via athena on an iceberg table, The performance is much poor compared to other columnar DBs like redshift and big query.